# How to obtain the maximum between element-pairs of two 2D matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

I have to calculate maximum of every unique pair of elements in matrix. So here is my code:

```
resultsMat = [
6   4   4;
0   2   6;
7   7   1;
5   1   73
];

copyMat = resultsMat;
for i=1:size(resultsMat,1)
        for j=1:size(resultsMat,2)
             for q=1:size(resultsMat,1)
                 for p=1:size(resultsMat,2)
                        if i== q && j ~= p
                        a = max(resultsMat(i,j),copyMat(q,p))
                        end
                 end
             end
        end
end
```

The problem comes when I try to store values in a matrix. For example:

```
[val ind] =  max(resultsMat(i,j),copyMat(q,p))
```

This throws an error:

```
Error using max
MAX with two matrices to compare and two output arguments is not supported.

Error in Untitled2 (line 18)
                        [a, b] = max(resultsMat(i,j),copyMat(q,p))
```

How to store values from `a = max(resultsMat(i,j),copyMat(q,p))` in a matrix?

Comment: What research have you done already? From what it seems `a` is a scalar, so storing that in a matrix should be easy and can be found on the internet

Comment: @Nathan, Already tried to find on internet but no lucky. Tried to find also on mtllab official documentation..

Comment: Then it is not clear to me what you actually want. You want the value of `a` stored in a matrix lets call it `M`?

Comment: Yes, all calculated values of "a".

Comment: So what's the desired result exactly, in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a larger (probably multi-dimensional) matrix, as every `(i,j)` location has a maximum vs any `(q,p)` location. This means that for every element in your first matrix, you obtain a full matrix of the same size. Saving as

```
matrix_with_results(i,j,q,p) = a
```

would do this. Then, given any combination of `i,j,q,p`, it returns the maximum.

Be sure to preallocate

```
matrix_with_results = zeros(size(resultsMat,1),size(resultsMat,2),size(resultsMat,1),size(resultsMat,2))
```

for speed.

---

Two notes:

- Don't use `i` or `j` as indices/variables names, [as they denote the imaginary unit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/5211833). Using those can easily lead to hard to debug errors.
- Initialise `matrix_with_results`, i.e. tell MATLAB how large it will be before going into the loop. Otherwise, MATLAB will have to increase its size every iteration,which is very slow. This is called [preallocation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html).